# virt_to_phys of a 64bit address yields large address value

Tags: linux, 64-bit, virtual-memory

I'm working on a 64bit device that has 3Gb of physical RAM. Within a kernel module, I'm trying to get the physical address of a buffer. But what I'm seeing is that the result of `virt_to_phys` is well beyond the 3Gb boundary of physical RAM:

```
u64 phys_ptr = virt_to_phys(buffer);
printk("virt=%p, phys=%p\n", buffer, (void *) phys_ptr);
```

The output is:

```
virt=ffffffbffc002000, phys=fffffffffc002000
```

The question is, what can I do to this physical pointer value to be within the range of 0x00000000 - 0xC0000000 (physical RAM itself)?

Comment: What if you print phys_ptr with '%16X' ?

Comment: Prints the same value. The pointer is valid.

Comment: How is the buffer allocated? `virt_to_phys` only works for certain kinda of buffers (direct mapped and kmalloc).

Comment: Looks like it's `vmalloc`. I guess walking the page table is the only solution...

Comment: Are you sure it's a RAM address? It would be a reasonable value for a PCI region (like a NIC card's memory mapped I/O or something). Would be interesting to see if this matches anything in `lspci -v` output